# many Distributors to many workers

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3, nservicebus-distributor, nservicebus4

We're a licensed product using NServiceBus as the messaging framework in our federated system.

Looking for opportunities for using it in a new feature-
Is there a way to build a multi-site system (scaled-out), at which each site/node produces and distributes messages to workers located on several nodes/sites?
Each distributor and worker can be hosted at it's own site (same LAN), and each site can go down at any point. All distributors and workers should be symmetric.

At first it looked like a classical "many producers to many competing consumers" problem. but I can't find a built-in way to achieve it with NServiceBus as, from what I saw, each worker can send health sings to only one distributor (I might be wrong about that).

Another issue I came against is with having a centralized RavenDB instance holding the distributor subscriptions. Having the RavenDB in it's own "availability group" requires additional resources. Is there a way to host the RavenDB instance under the same sites, having their data replicated while each site is using it's local DB instance? This will also bind the HA of the distributors to their subscription DB's.

Reading this discussion- http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/18412
It seems that NServiceBus requires a cluster to keep HA of the published data. But why can’t the distributor wait for an acknowledge that the msg was successfully consumed & processed by the worker, and keep retrying to publish it to the same or a different worker? This way, even if the VM went down with data in the queues, the data will be sent to another node which is available at that time.

Edit: Tried to ask the same at NServiceBus official Yahoo group but keep getting pythonError within the yahoo group.

Thanks in advance,
Rami Prilutsky, dbMotion